# .net Components ... a Custom Form

Tags: vb.net, components

I've been working in the creation of some custom components adding functionalites to the basic components such as a Datagridview.

Now I want to create a custom Form ... I mean, when I choose add new item in the VS menu, there is a Windows form and some varians of it like an about box, or Dialog, that are simple Forms with a custom controls already on it.

I want to have a login form for my set of applications, so this login is avialable for all the development team to use it in the different modules.

How can I develop the form and then add it to the "Add New Item" screen?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Way to create a Form with special usage, and then deploy it to other applications, like a login screen.

I used the Inherit Forms :) ...  here is some documentations, it was really easy !!!

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/inheripckr_2.htm

The form is later deploy using a dll just like a component.

Greetigns !!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this (assuming you use MSVS 2010, if not, there should be articles for other versions):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247069.aspx

Comment: there is even a video tutorial for msvs2008 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc700976.aspx